# In Flutter, how to call a function when the focus changes from one textfield to another textfield?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter desktop app. In Flutter, how to call a function when the focus moves from one text field to another? I tried `onEditingComplete` but it only calls `_handleLoadType` when I press the enter button on the textfield.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
                controller: vehicleNoController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'VehicleNo'),
                onEditingComplete: () {
                  // Call the function when moving to the next text field (LoadType)
                  _handleLoadType();
                }),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextField(
              controller: loadTypeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'LoadType'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleLoadType() async {
    print('found');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try `FocusNode`

1. Declare the variable

```dart
final focusNode = FocusNode();
```

2. Add listener at `initState` of `StatefulWidget`. If unfocused, run function.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  focusNode.addListener(() {
    if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
      // Run function
    }
  });
}
```

1. Dispose it at `dispose` method of the `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  focusNode.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

3. Assign it to `TextField`

```dart
TextField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
...
```